# how to get unique key from firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a website of restaurant using firebase.
The structure is like this

```
food
  dessert
    item1
    item2
    item3
```

I want the data to be added with same key continuation. This way
food
dessert
item1
item2
item3
item4
item5

and so on.

I tried this:

```
let nextKey = 1;

// Retrieve data once to find the next available key
get(ref(dessertsRef)).then((snapshot) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(snapshot.val() || {});
  const maxKey = keys.reduce(
    (max, key) => Math.max(max, parseInt(key.replace("item", ""))),
    0
  );
  nextKey = maxKey + 1;

  // Add dessert data to Firebase with the next available key
  set(ref(dessertsRef, `item${nextKey}`), {
    name: name,
    description: description,
    price: price,
    type: type,
    imageUrl: imageUrl,
  });
```

Comment: could not follow . explain what exactly you want ?

Comment: You really shouldn't try to do this.  It doesn't scale well.  Firebase has a [push operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-push) that lets you add children with random IDs.  The linked documentation even tells you that trying to use ordered, numbered keys is a bad idea. If you need to sort those children, given them a nested value to sort on instead of trying to use the key.